# Explain what I am doing wrong with my HTTP POST to Yo

Tags: c#, http, post

I have never done any posting data before and I think I may have missed something, I am trying to send a POST to [Yo](http://www.justyo.co) using what [help I have](https://medium.com/@YoAppStatus/yo-developers-api-e7f2f0ec5c3c) but I am still left a bit confused.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["api_token"] = "<API I was sent>";
    var response = wb.UploadValues("http://api.justyo.co/yoall/", "POST", data);
}
```

Correct api token used, I'm not 100% sure about the data names "username" nor "password" but I couldn't see anything that said anything else and the names make sense.

---

(IYDK: Yo is a no character social messaging app which you tap a name and it will send a "yo" notification, the POST should send a 'yo' to everyone on my contacts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more information by using code below ?

`var message = string.Format("\nResponse received was :\n{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response));`

and

I develop a single app and it works, hope it helps.

`https://github.com/cguldogan/YoSharp`

Answer (score 1):

If you would read the api documentation you would see this:

> HTTP POST using your favorite language or “curl —data “api_token=” http://api.justyo.co/yoall/”

U can clearly see that you only have to send the "api_token"

try this:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["api_token"] = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_API_TOKEN";
    var response = wb.UploadValues("http://api.justyo.co/yoall/", "POST", data);
}
```

Comment: I have tried just sending the api_token and it hasn't worked.

Comment: Can You give me the response message of this request pls?